# I want to read data from text file and save it to database in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to `Django` and `Python`. I want to read data from text file and save it to `database`.

Input file example:

```
E Alan Marshall 121 55.26 
E Bob Marley 122 66.78
M Ted Smith Marketing 123 76.78 
M Ron Barly Production 124 86.78
```

I have described `models` as follows:

```
class Employee(models.Model):   
        first = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        id = models.IntegerField()
        pay = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

class Manager(models.Model):
        first = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        department = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        id = models.IntegerField()
        pay = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

I receive data in the form of a text file and I read the data by parsing the string. The first character tells me the type of class data to expect (e.g. E means Employee class object data, M means manager class object data)
Once we know the type of data, the sequence in which the variables occur are fixed. Means if I tokenize string with 'space' as delimiter, for Employee class, first element is first Name, next is last name, next is employee id, next is pay

I want to write code in `python` which will parse the input file and will create objects of the respective class.
I should maintain the type of class variable too

```
type of
            first is string
            last is string
            id is interger
            pay is float
            department is string
```

I was planning to write generic function to parse and create the objects of classes.
It will read file line by line, tokenize the line and will call function to generate object of the class.
`"generateClassObject"` function will take dictionary of variable name and their type as input. (e.g. for `Employee class {"first":"string", "last":"string", "id":"integer", "pay":"float" }`, for Manager `class {"first":"string", "last":"string", "department":"string" "id":"integer", "pay":"float" }`)
and will return the class object.

The function will look something like

```
generateClassObject(className, dictionary, tokenizedData):
    # instantiate class object based on className (How to do this?)
    # read dictionary one by one and assign value to respective variable of
      # class object from tokenizedData by converting string data to proper
      # type (How to do this?)
    # save class object to database (I know how to do this)
```

Is it possible create objects of class `dynamically` in `python`?.
How to instantiate class object based on `className`?.
How to convert string data into proper datatype if we know the proper datatype in `python`? .

Comment: are you familiar with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class method.

```
class Employee(models.Model):   
        first = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        id = models.IntegerField()
        pay = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

        @classmethod
        def from_file(cls, line):
            # parse line of input here
            emp = cls.create(first=first, last=last, id=id, pay=pay)
            return emp

# code to read from file
line = file.readline()
if line.startswith("E"): 
    bob = Employee()
    bob.from_file(line)
    # add code to save to database
```

Further reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd seriously question why you have separate models for Manager and Employee even though they have the same fields. It'd be much better to have a single model with a `role` field.

Still, if you really do want to do this, you just need to keep a dictionary mapping the code to the model.

```
models = {
    'E': Employee,
    'M': Manager
}
instance = models[class_name].objects.create(**params)
```

Comment: I provided this as a representative example. The data I am working on is totally different. But thanks for the suggestion, I will use it if encounter a similar situation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @DanielRoseman's recommendation. But as for a general answer starting from a **text file**

```
import re
from project.models import CorporatePerson
with open('input_file.txt') as ifile:
    s = ifile.readline()
    m = re.search('([E,M]) (.{1,}) (.{1,}) (.{1,}) (.{1,}) (.{1,})', s)
    CorporatePerson.objects.create(
    role=m.group(0)
    first =m.group(1)
    department=m.group(2)
    id=m.group(3)
    pay=m.group(4)
    )
```

**This requires that you add something like `none` for `department` for each `employee` in your input file.**

If you want to stick to 2 models, you can use an `if` statement to use whether to save it to an `Employee` or `Manager` model, then match each of them with their own `regex`, but you get the point...

I understand this does not do the tokenization talked about in your post, but this offers an easier (and maybe more quick and dirty solution) that's written and changed very easily.

If this is a tool you would be using and adapting over and over again, I would create a class that could digest a text file that can vary in number of properties (or columns)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Creating a class that can digest varying text file is a good idea.